# Drive letter disappeared on triple-boot install

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, drive-letter

I have Windows 7, Ubuntu and Windows XP installed. I first installed Windows 7 than Ubuntu and than Windows XP. My Windows 7 is on C drive, Ubuntu is on a logical drive in my extended partition and Windows xp is on a primary partition F. I have another primary partition E on which for some reason when i installed Windows XP it placed boot.int file on it. I am using grub to boot the three operating system.

Yesterday, i reinstalled Windows 7 and after the installation i saw that the drive letter from drive E was gone. I tried to restore but it was not available from the drop down menu in Computer Management and it is not assigned to any other drive. I had to assign another letter to make the drive visible in windows explorer.

My question is how to recover the letter E on this partition and why it is not available?

The other problem i have is Windows XP can't boot now and i think it some how related to this missing E drive letter.

Edit: The letter E was assigned to the CD-ROM device.

Comment: You are (covertly) asking two questions. And the follow-up answer isn't that good, as Windows 7 can recognize and multi-boot with BCD.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that Windows XP can't recognise Windows 7 and Windows 7 can't recognize Ubuntu. You have to install the OS starting from the lower version. Please install XP first, then Windows 7 and lastly Ubuntu. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7, (based on experience from Vista) can recognize a lot of things and partitions.
As I said, you were asking two questions in covert.

**First question:** How to recover the E:/ Partition?

On Windows 7, try to explore the [Disk Management](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-manage-your-disks-using-disk-management-utility) utility as indicated. Possibly, the partition is there, it just isn't assigned a letter, due to the reinstall of Windows 7.

**Second question:** How to multiboot with Windows 7, Windows XP and Ubuntu.

Windows 7 has its own bootloader called BCD (Boot Configuration Data for short). It probably overwrote grub as the default bootloader. So, I direct you to [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2676-bcdedit-how-use.html) and [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm) links for further information on how to allow all systems to multiboot.